# Before save call back ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am doing a currently a project and I am using a devise.. In my sign up(using the devise) I have field named mobile number, when I click the sign up/submit button it will be save into my table but before it will save I concatenate the country code(+63. Example: I input 1234567891, in my table it will become like this +631234567891).

I used the before_save method/function but I am having a problem with it, whenever I click the sign in/confirm email/logout it will add another +63(so it will become +63+63....)..

Question: How can I prevent adding +63? It will only add the +63 during the sign-up

**Model**

```
before_save : add_country_code

validates :mobile_no, :presence => true,
              :numericality => true,
              :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 10 }
def add_country_code
    self.mobile_no = "+63" + self.mobile_no.to_s
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Only update the mobile phone if the object is not persisted.

```
def add_country_code
  self.mobile_no = "+63" + self.mobile_no.to_s unless persisted?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
before_save :add_country_code, unless: :mobile_no
```

- this only appends +63 when the `mobile_no` is blank (which happens only at sign-up, or when updating your user information provided that there was no `mobile_no` yet)

Comment: I think there's some correct to your code.. it must be unless :mobile_no

Comment: Annd sir, now it didt add the country code when I submitted it

Comment: I did not know you could add `, unless:`!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `before_save` with `before_create`. Whenever you sign in, *devise* updates some other columns like `last_signed_in_at`, therefore `before_save` is triggered.

But really you might want to check if you have prefixed the country code, in case the user wants to update the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Your validates method is having length as 10 and that’s why while saving it is checking validation. Change validation as follows:

```
validates :mobile_no, presence: true,
              numericality: true,
              length: { is: 13 }
```

Keeping length 13 will allow you save **+63** before saving.
Hope this helps. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_country_code
  self.mobile_no = '+63' << self.mobile_no.to_s.gsub(/\A\+63/, '')
end
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.